# Android REST POST loses Date value

Tags: java, android, rest, gson, android-annotations

I have an Android App (Spring Android + Android Annotations + Gson) that consume REST services from a Web App (Jersey + Spring + Hibernate / JPA). The problem is that my java.util.Date properties are not serialized:

**Activity (Android App):**

```
...
@Click(R.id.buttonLogin)
void onLoginClick() {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setDateRegistration(new Date()); //Property where the problem occurs
    student.setFirstName("Venilton");
    student.setGender(Gender.M);

    doSomethingInBackground(student);
}

@Background
void doSomethingInBackground(Student student) {
    this.restClient.insert(student);
}
...
```

**Rest Client (Android App):**

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://MY_IP:8080/restful-app", 
    converters = { GsonHttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface StudentRESTfulClient {

    @Post("/student/insert")
    Student insert(Student student);
}
```

**Rest Server (Web App):**

```
@Component
@Path("/student")
public class StudentRESTfulServer {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentServiceJpa;

    @POST 
    @Path("/insert")
    public Student insert(Student student) {
        //student.getDateRegistration() is null! It's a problem!

        Student studentResponse = null;
        try {
                this.studentServiceJpa.insert(student);
                studentResponse = student;
        } catch (Exception exception) { }

        return studentResponse;
    }
}
```

**The Android application performs the POST the Student object for REST service, but the DateRegistration property loses its value when the student object arrives in StudentRESTfulServer.**

Could you help me?

Comment: please post your student model from client and server. I've the strong feeling Date() isn't serializable over json, so you should use either a string or a long value.

Comment: Hi @MemLeak, my Student entity is well:
`@XmlRootElement`
`public class Student implements Serializable {`
    `@Column(name = "date_last_login", nullable = false)`
    `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`
    `private Date dateLastLogin;`

Comment: try to store the Timestamp as long not as Date: student.setDateRegistration(System.currentTimeMillis())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Gson doesn't know how to properly serialize your date (a bit weird that it doesn't throw anything into the log, or does it?)

The simple solution would be setting Gson date format you are going to use.
For this you need to create custom converter and use it instead of `GsonHttpMessageConverter`

**CustomHttpMessageConverter.java**

```
CustomHttpMessageConverter extends GsonHttpMessageConverter {
    protected static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    protected static Gson buildGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

        gsonBuilder.setDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    public CustomHttpMessageConverter()  {
        super(buildGson());
    }
}
```

Then in your **REST Client (Android app)**

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://MY_IP:8080/restful-app", 
converters = { CustomHttpMessageConverter.class })
```

And that should work just fine.

**If still not working**

Then you can add whatever settings you need for Gson inside `buildGson` method, e.g. you can register custom serializers if you need some:

```
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonDateDeSerializer());
```

but then you'd need to implement `JsonDeserializer` and `JsonSerializer` interfaces within your `GsonDateDeSerializer` class.

For custom serializing/deserializing you can check out my other answer: [GSON Serialize boolean to 0 or 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607088/gson-serialize-boolean-to-0-or-1/12894916#12894916)

Comment: Damian Walczak thanks for your answer! Makes perfect sense to me, as soon as possible will test.